# The canvas of my game is zoomed out like on a computer

Tags: android, iphone, mobile, canvas, html5-canvas

I made a game that with HTML5 made for mobile phones. I tried and developed it for Firefox OS and it works perfectly on Firefox OS as an application.

I then tried it on an Android browser (Android 2.x) and on an iPod running iOS 4 or 5 (not sure which), but the game is completely zoomed out like on a computer. This is my CSS, I'm using the HTML5 canvas tag:

```
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#canvas {
  position: absolute;
}
```

Also on Firefox OS, not only does it work as a packaged application as does it work inside the browser. I used the default browser on both iOS and Android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

may be not closeness but do you use [viewport](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/viewport-meta-tag-for-non-responsive-design).? this is very extended article about `viewport` and i recomended if you use `meta viewport` on iphone or android(smart phone), put this `content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"` it is very usefull.

Answer (score 0):

Is it quarter the size of the screen? It might be that you haven't taken in to account the retina display?

(I know you have it working well under Firefox OS but is this on a retina/high-res sceen device?)

If this is indeed the case, you can get the scale ratio with `window.devicePixelRatio`.